# How to assign values to functions in R

Tags: r

In R language there are some functions like names and dimnames which you can assign values to them as example:

```
x <- list('foo'=2, boo=3)
names(x) # This returns ("foo", "boo") vector
names(x) <- c("moo", "doo") # Changes existing item names to ("moo", "doo")
```

My question is how to create such functions which apparently they act as set and get functions at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps `setNames(list('foo'=2, boo=3), c('moo', 'doo'))`

Comment: `names` and `names<-` are actually different functions. They are generics, so you can define methods for them.

Comment: @Roland as I understand from your comment there is a function `names<-` which is used to change names attribute. I will be thank full if you told me how to create any function lets say `func<-` so that I can change other attributes.

Comment: I guess you might be looking for something like: `second = function(x) x[2]; "second<-" = function(x, value) { x[2] = value; x }`. `xx = 1:3; second(xx); second(xx) = 4; xx`

Comment: @alexis_laz Nice. I hope you don't mind me including this in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You encountered a special kind of function. From the [language definition (section 3.1.3 Function calls)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Function-calls):

> A special type of function calls can appear on the left hand side of
>   the assignment operator as in
>
> `class(x) <- "foo"`
>
> What this construction really does is to call the function `class<-` with the original object and the right hand side.
>   This function performs the modification of the object and returns the
>   result which is then stored back into the original variable. (At least
>   conceptually, this is what happens. Some additional effort is made to
>   avoid unnecessary data duplication.)

Such functions are `.Primitive` functions. They call internal C code. Usually they are generic functions, which means you can define methods for them.

@alexis_laz demonstrates how to create such a function in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475971/how-to-assign-values-to-functions-in-r/29476323#comment47113778_29475971):

```
second <- function(x) x[2]
"second<-" <- function(x, value) { x[2] <- value; x }
xx <- 1:3
second(xx)
#[1] 2
second(xx) <- 4
xx
#[1] 1 4 3
```

Comment: Thank you. while this is not a solution but it might be a good indication that I should stop searching any more in this direction.

Comment: That was what I looking for so many thanks to you to point out that I need this kind of function and thanks to  @alexis_laz as he showed me how to create it.

Comment: It's interesting to note that `value` is well defined here and can't be replaced with any of `foo` or `bar` as we like to do.

Comment: @AdamO Yes, see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment